# SimplePie double feed link, Mybb syndication

Tags: rss, feed, simplepie, mybb

i have a website in joomla, and forum: MYBB, 
i installed simplepie to show last posts on my home page, 
It works, 
But i have only 2 little problems

1. The update links are posting on a new line so it becmes double, i want it to be updated
2. The RE: before every reply, i want this to be deleted

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPGhW.png

code:

```
  <?php require_once('php/autoloader.php');
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_feed_url('http://localhost//forum/syndication2.php');
    $feed->enable_cache(false);
    $feed->init();
    $feed->handle_content_type();
    ?>


<?php foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 10) as $item): ?>

<li><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(1, 1); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You should be able to use a regex to remove the RE:. Not sure what you mean by the update link - seems like you'd have to handle that in your loop.

Comment: i mean : when i get a new reply the thread link on my home page gets a new line, so it becomes double: http://i.imgur.com/MHDAl7A.png ... 
example: Test thread have new 3 comments, instead of 1 line i get each time a new line.